# Enums in EF4 POCO Generated Objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

Since EF4 is lacking enum support, I've been trying to implement the workaround listed at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx?PageIndex=1&CommentPosted=true#comments

However, I'm using the POCO generator for EF4 (which the article does NOT use) and I keep getting the following runtime error:

***Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType...***

Presumably this is because CreateObjectSet doesn't understand the wrapper class.

Has anyone been able to find a suitable solution for supporting enums in EF4 with generated POCOs?

Thanks.

Comment: will you accept answer or close question?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, enum type properties are not supported by EF4 (or CTP5); of course we need them, and I've heard that they will be implemented next release.

Here is a workaround:

```
public enum FieldDataType
{ 
    Image,
    RawText,
    Ajax
}

public class DefinitionDynamicField
{
    public int FieldType { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public FieldDataType FieldTypeObserver 
    { 
        get { return (FieldDataType)FieldType; }
        set { return FieldType = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

We use `FieldTypeObserver` instead of  `FieldType`.

It is ugly but it works.

Comment: now; EF4.3.1 and EF5 support enum types. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx

Comment: are you sure about EF4.3.1? I had a look at the link and while it says its there for EF5, I don't see it being mentioned for EF4.3.1 - I can't get it working on EF4.3.1 either.

Comment: you are right. I'm really sorry for that. only EF5 support enum types.